(C#/Mono.Cecil) Determining all exit instructions of a Method using just OpCodes
While making a game with Unity, was looking for a similar solution to PostSharp's OnMethodBoundaryAspect.OnExitas described in this blog.
However, it doesn't look like PostSharp can be used with Unity unless you build it as a DLL (and even then its not clear what platforms will support it, should an older version be used etc.).
I've been looking at a 3rd party lib under MIT license which uses Mono.Cecil to weave equivalent OnEntry/OnExit definitions but it doesn't capture exceptions on the OnExit, just inserts a call before the last Instruction in the function.
Given that exception throws/rethrows can be try/catch'ed how could one determine from the sequence of Instructions (each one has an OpCode) which instructions actually exit the function?
Tried inserting before every OpCodes.Ret which was fine for early return calls but obviously found that exception handling wouldn't use OpCodes.Ret and simply checking for OpCodes.Throw/OpCodes.Rethrow does not indicate which would exit the function.
Edit: Also realized OpCodes.Ret check doesn't play well with coroutine use of 'yield return'.
Edit2: Exceptions thrown by functions called in the function body would not be detectable this way.
Edit3: Functions that end on iterator statements such as foreach are not exited by OpCodes.Ret.

I'm wondering what exactly you are trying to achieve .. if you are making the game you basically speak about your own code ... So you wouldn't really require any weaving here but can Just directly handle exceptions etc right?

As discussed when this was in review... The easiest way to catch all exceptions being thrown by your method is to wrap the entire method in a try/catch. This will also catch exceptions thrown by other methods which your method calls. Even for enumerator methods, exceptions are thrown directly from MoveNext, so wrapping MoveNext in a try/catch should suffice?

I'd like to use IL Weaving in Mono.Cecil to implement a decorator pattern using attributes on game code., to reduce boilerplate and improve readability. However, PostSharp is not compatible with Mono and Unity migration from Mono is at least 2 years away.
An example use case would be marking functions as critical regions and applying locks on those regions with a argument in the attribute to set a category of lock, I may use this with an async event queue or callback system that have predicates on execution related to these locks.
Clearly my question is not very concise, apologies.

@canton7 issue with the IEnumerators might come from Unity using them as "Coroutine" so the MoveNext is called internally by the engine itself after registering the IEnumerator as a Coroutine

@derHugo I know, yes

@canton7 what I mean is OP can not wrap MoveNext with a try-catch here as you suggest as OP isn't calling move next

Why can't OP wrap MoveNext in a try/catch? MoveNext is called whenever Unity moves to the next stage of a coroutine

@canton7 as mentioned that happens somewhere inside the engine core itself .. OP doesn't call MoveNext anywhere "manually" and therefore can also not wrap it with anything .. all we know is that the MoveNext is somehow invoked by the engine similar to Update and other message methods .. unless you can tell us where exactly the coroutines are invoked from and how to intercept/weave a try-catch around it

@derHugo The suggestion is to inject the try/catch code into the MoveNext method itself, not into the place which calls MoveNext. OP's question talks about injecting code into the return points in methods.
